# how to use the janrain engage widget in an iOS native application which is built using Appcelerator's Titanium?

Tags: ios, titanium, janrain, titanium-mobile, rpxnow

I've developed an iOS application using the Appcelerator's Titanium framework, I want to integrate the janrain login widget to my iOS application. Is anyone tried this? If so can you please help me to do this.

Thanks,
Siva...

Comment: Nobody used the janrain widget in their iOS application so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link shows how to use janrain in ios and android in titanium.

https://github.com/euforic/Janrain-Titanium-Appcelerator

I hope this will helps you.

Comment: thanks sagaridev, your information really helped me to resolve my issues.

Comment: Is this code throwing "Data not found error" ? I am suffering from that.Do you have any solution for it? Please check my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739082/getting-data-not-found-error-in-janrain-titanium